# Trying to access upvote and downvote with StackExhange API JSON request

Tags: jquery, json, api

I'm just getting started with the Stack Exchange API, and for this task I'm trying to return a list of latest posts with upvote and downvote numbers. I'm using jQuery and the Ajax method.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            pagesize: 20,
            filter_type: 'unsafe',
            included_fields: ['questions.up_vote_count','questions.down_vote_count'],
            site: 'stackoverflow'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(data.items, function (i, data) {
                var question_list = '<li><span class=votes><b class=upvote>' + data.up_vote_count + '</b><b class=downvote>' + data.down_vote_count + '</b></span><a href="' + data.link + '">' + data.title + '</a></li>';
                $('ul.list-items').append(question_list);
            });
        }
    });
```

I understand I need to set a filter and included fields as the up and down vote data isn't included by default. My code returns `undefined` when I call the up and down data. Can any one show how I am doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not set the custom filter correctly. I checked the usage of questions API and generated [this filter for the query](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions#pagesize=20&order=desc&sort=activity&filter=cvwvFLMyvV&site=stackoverflow).

You may be able to specify the fields such as `questions.up_vote_count` in a named custom query, but for now this will suffice:

```
data: {
    pagesize: 20,
    filter: 'cvwvFLMyvV',
    site: 'stackoverflow'
    }
```

See the results here: http://jsfiddle.net/UvjFR/

Comment: Is this API related? I know reputation and privileges are meant to establish roles in the community, but does it really effect API limitations?

Comment: I would think if they felt it was a feature only certain people should access that the limitation would extend to the API. I don't know for sure.

Comment: What I'm having trouble understanding is how they limit and grant it - my Ajax call is simply calling their JSON data to my app, which has no association with my Stack account. Does this mean in order to use that specific data I'd have to register my app with an API key, which in turn links it to my account?

Comment: Thanks! I still can't get it to work, but I changed the post context so I opened a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17149774/cant-get-post-data-from-stack-exhange-api-json-call any ideas?