# Can't get post data from Stack Exhange API JSON call

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to dynamically fill a *post* area in my app with data from a Stack Exhange post ID using JSON and jQuery, but I can't seem to get the data to fill in the elements.

```
/* Get post info */
function getPost(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/questions/' + id,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: 'jsonp',
        data: {
            filter: 'cvwvFLMyvV',
            site: 'stackoverflow',
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('article.post-view div.post-info h2').text(data.title);
            $('article.post-view div.post-entry').html(data.body);
        }
    });
}

/* Click to toggle */
$('body').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    var postID = $(this).data('id');
    getPost(postID);
});
```

HTML:

```
<article class=post-view>
    <div class=post-content>
        <div class=post-info>
            <h2></h2>
        </div>
        <div class=post-entry></div>
    </div>
</article>

<a href="#" data-id="628500" class=postfill>Click Me!</a>
```

Here's what I'm doing: http://jsfiddle.net/c4WRk/2/

But the `getPost()` doesn't seem to work. Anyone know how I do this properly?

Comment: *"doesn't seem to work"* means what? The `div.loading` is not showing? The Ajax request is not made? The response is not received? The elements are not updated? Please provide more information. Note that you didn't include jQuery in your fiddle, so that does not work for sure.

Comment: I updated the fiddle and code sample to reflect jQuery and removed the loading element, as it was irrelevant. I simply don't know how to the function isn't working. This is my first time using the API and JSON so I'm a little rough on it.

Comment: you are simply using the data incorrectly. response object contains an array of items that have the properties you are looking for. `console.log(data)`. Also, you don't need `jsonp: "jsonp"`

Comment: I don't need JSONP? I thought that was necessary for cross-domain JSON due to browser restrictions?

Comment: @KevinB: You are right, it works without, but then the [documentation](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage) is a bit confusing: *"All API responses are JSON, we do support JSONP with the `jsonp` query parameter."*

Comment: You probably want `data.items[0].title`. Always look at the data first before you are trying to access it (with `console.log` or `console.dir`).

Comment: @JodyHeavener That means, `http://mysite.com/?callback=somecallbackname`. `dataType: "jsonp"` is enough to get that url parameter added.

Comment: @KevinB: Oh, wrong docs. The API v2 uses the `callback` parameter: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys!! Adding `items[0]` to my data query made the title work, but I still can't seem to get ‘data.items[0].body` to work. I imagine this has something to do with my `filter`, right? Because by default the body isn't included I'm the regular filter. Here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c4WRk/4/

Comment: Never mind, got it! I didn't have the correct filter set. Thanks again guys!!